# Where are the sources and issue tracker of Ghandicam?

Tags: video

I want to report a bug in [Gandhicam](http://www.gandhicam.org/), and possibly fix it.
But I can't find Gandhicam's bug tracker not source code.
Any idea where they are? Not found via Google.

Gandhicam is an application for live video/photo upload, aiming to help whistle-blowers protect civil liberties, making phone confiscation pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like Gandhicam is dead...

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure it is open source, as I could not find any reference to it being so, but you can try using the [Contact link](http://www.gandhicam.org/contact) on their website to report the bug.

Comment: Yes, I contacted them already, actually :-) No answer so far.